# $A$ is representable as a difference of two closed sets if and only if $\overline A \setminus A$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Show that the set $A$ is representable as a difference of two closed sets if and only if $\overline A \setminus A$ is closed.

---

**My try:**
$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $\overline A \setminus A$ is closed. Since $\overline A$ is closed and  $A = \overline A \setminus (\overline A \setminus A)$, we see that $A$ is represented as a difference of two closed sets. $\square$
$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $A = B\setminus C$ where $B$ and $C$ are closed sets. We need to show that $\overline A \setminus A$ is closed. Since $\overline A = \overline {B\setminus C}$, we have $$\overline A \setminus A = (\overline {B\setminus C}) \setminus (B \setminus C) = \partial (B\setminus C)$$ Since the boundary is closed (?), $\overline A \setminus A$ is closed $\square$

---

Last arguments of mine seem to be vague not clear. How to solve the problem rigorously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof of $\implies$:
$\overline A \setminus A =\overline  {(B\setminus C)} \cap (B^{c} \cup C)$. Since $\overline  {(B\setminus C)} \cap B^{c} $ is empty we get $\overline A \setminus A =\overline  {(B\setminus C)} \cap  C$ which is closed.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong but shouldn't the last $\cup$ be $\cap$ since $X \cap (Y \cup Z) = (X\cap Y) \cup (X \cap Z)$?

Comment: @NodeJS Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: That transformation was so nice in the beginning! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The first half is of course fine. The problem with the second half is that

$$\operatorname{cl}(B\setminus C)\setminus(B\setminus C)$$

is not necessarily the boundary of $B\setminus C$. In the real line, for instance, take $B=[0,2]$ and $C=[0,1]$; then $B\setminus C=(1,2]$ and $\operatorname{cl}(B\setminus C)=[1,2]$, so

$$\operatorname{cl}(B\setminus C)\setminus(B\setminus C)=\{1\}\,,$$

but $\operatorname{bdry}(B\setminus C)=\{1,2\}$.

Clearly $A\subseteq B$, and $B$ is closed, so $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq B$, and therefore

$$(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C=A\,.$$

On the other hand, $A\cap C=\varnothing$, so $A\subseteq(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus C$. Thus, $A=(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus C$.

- To complete the argument, show that $(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus A=C\cap\operatorname{cl}A$, which is of course closed.

Comment: I would definitely accept this answer if I could do twice! Wouldn't you mind if I left the tick on another answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: @NodeJS: That’s entirely up to you; I don’t mind a bit. And you’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

Your equality $$(\overline {B\setminus C}) \setminus (B \setminus C) = \partial (B\setminus C)$$ is wrong.

For a set $S$ you have

$$\partial S = \overline S \setminus \mathring{S}.$$

Comment: If $B \setminus C$ is open, then that equality is true, else that should be equal to $\emptyset$?

Comment: @NodeJS What is $\overline {\mathbb Q } \setminus \mathbb Q$? Is it the boundary of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The closure is $\mathbb R$ then $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q = \mathbb I$?

Comment: @NodeJS Yes, and the boundary is the entire real line. So it is wrong to say that the boundary of  a set is its closure minus the set.